# C# Allow method to run only if other method is not running

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have some dataset, which can be read or updated. I want to make sure that it's not read by any thread while update method is running, but multiple reads at the same time are allowed. The best solution I came up with is:

```
object lockObject = new object();

public SomeOutputData Read(SomeParam someParams)
{
    lock (lockObject) {} //wait if Update() is running
    //read
}

public void Update(SomeInputData data)
{
    lock (lockObject) 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1); //to give any Read() methods time to complete execution
        //update
    }
}
```

Of course, this solution is inefficient and have obvious flaws. Is it any right way to do this?

Comment: you are probably looking for [Readers–writer lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @EmilTerman Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim) is a newer, and probably better, tool for the job. Btw I don't understand the reason for the line `Thread.Sleep(1)` in you code. IMHO it serves no useful role.